# SSH with RCA key does not authorized

Tags: ssh, debian, putty, raspbian, rca

I try to set up an ssh connection by RCA-key. Settings for PuTTy: 192.168.1.41, port 22, the private key was choosed.

1. My public key has placed "192.168.1.41/home/pi/.ssh/PuTKey.pub" therefore I should enter a command `cat ~/.ssh/PutKey.pub | ssh pi@192.168.1.41 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` but console replied me `/root/.ssh/PuTKey.` file or folder does not exist, then required the password. What does it mean? Maybe was file *.pub caught?
2. Then, I set up `PasswordAuthentication no` and login required. why?
   log:

```
Jul  2 09:30:01 raspberrypi systemd-logind[392]: New session c5 of user pi.
Jul  2 09:30:08 raspberrypi sshd[1775]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
Jul  2 09:30:08 raspberrypi systemd-logind[392]: Removed session c5.
Jul  2 09:31:29 raspberrypi sshd[1816]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 55675 [preauth]
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi sshd[1919]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.1.41 port 57772 ssh2
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi sshd[1919]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi systemd-logind[392]: New session c6 of user pi.
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi sshd[1940]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.41 port 57772:11: disconnected by user
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi sshd[1940]: Disconnected from 192.168.1.41 port 57772
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi sshd[1919]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
Jul  2 09:47:37 raspberrypi systemd-logind[392]: Removed session c6.
Jul  2 10:02:14 raspberrypi sshd[502]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul  2 10:02:14 raspberrypi sshd[1988]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  2 10:02:14 raspberrypi sshd[1988]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  2 10:03:21 raspberrypi sshd[1990]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 58683 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:04:07 raspberrypi sshd[2003]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.41 port 57774 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2029]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 10:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2029]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 10:44:12 raspberrypi sshd[2135]: Invalid user  from 192.168.1.34 port 61045
Jul  2 10:44:12 raspberrypi sshd[2135]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  2 10:44:13 raspberrypi sshd[2135]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61045 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:44:24 raspberrypi su[1640]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 10:44:29 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: New seat seat0.
Jul  2 10:44:31 raspberrypi sshd[500]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  2 10:44:31 raspberrypi sshd[500]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  2 10:44:33 raspberrypi lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 10:44:33 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: New session c1 of user pi.
Jul  2 10:44:33 raspberrypi systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 10:44:36 raspberrypi polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.12 [lxpolkit], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale ru_RU.UTF-8)
Jul  2 10:45:52 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 10:48:32 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session ended: user pi
Jul  2 10:48:40 raspberrypi vncpamhelper: pam_unix(vncserver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=pi
Jul  2 10:48:48 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 10:48:52 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session ended: user pi
Jul  2 10:49:20 raspberrypi sshd[1157]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61390 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:49:30 raspberrypi sshd[1160]: Invalid user  from 192.168.1.34 port 61416
Jul  2 10:49:30 raspberrypi sshd[1160]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  2 10:49:31 raspberrypi sshd[1160]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61416 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:49:42 raspberrypi sshd[1165]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61432 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:51:26 raspberrypi sshd[1172]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61565 [preauth]
Jul  2 10:59:27 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 11:01:41 raspberrypi sshd[1210]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 63170 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:03:08 raspberrypi sshd[1213]: Invalid user bv from 192.168.1.34 port 63198
Jul  2 11:03:08 raspberrypi sshd[1213]: input_userauth_request: invalid user bv [preauth]
Jul  2 11:03:09 raspberrypi sshd[1213]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 63198 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:04:59 raspberrypi sshd[1228]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 63563 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:11:29 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session ended: user pi
Jul  2 11:11:36 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 11:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1287]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1287]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 11:17:37 raspberrypi sshd[1302]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 64790 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi su[1394]: Successful su for root by root
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi su[1394]: + /dev/pts/0 root:root
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi su[1394]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:42:51 raspberrypi su[1394]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi su[1437]: Successful su for root by root
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi su[1437]: + /dev/pts/2 root:root
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi su[1437]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:43:53 raspberrypi su[1437]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jul  2 11:44:34 raspberrypi sshd[1449]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.41 port 38800 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:46:30 raspberrypi sshd[1468]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.41 port 38802 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:46:46 raspberrypi sshd[500]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul  2 11:46:46 raspberrypi sshd[1481]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  2 11:46:46 raspberrypi sshd[1481]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi sshd[1484]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.1.41 port 38804 ssh2
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi sshd[1484]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: New session c2 of user pi.
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi sshd[1494]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.41 port 38804:11: disconnected by user
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi sshd[1494]: Disconnected from 192.168.1.41 port 38804
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi sshd[1484]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
Jul  2 11:46:54 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: Removed session c2.
Jul  2 11:47:41 raspberrypi sshd[1481]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul  2 11:47:41 raspberrypi sshd[1529]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  2 11:47:41 raspberrypi sshd[1529]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  2 11:48:14 raspberrypi sshd[1530]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 51793 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:48:56 raspberrypi sshd[1536]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 51847 [preauth]
Jul  2 11:49:56 raspberrypi sshd[1539]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 51910 [preauth]
Jul  2 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2018]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2018]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 13:17:02 raspberrypi CRON[2206]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 13:17:02 raspberrypi CRON[2206]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 13:19:05 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session ended: user pi
Jul  2 14:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2413]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 14:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2413]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 15:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2585]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 15:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2585]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 16:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2770]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 16:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2770]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 17:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2957]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 17:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[2957]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 18:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[3163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 18:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[3163]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 19:15:20 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 19:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[3592]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 19:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[3592]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 19:23:48 raspberrypi sshd[3625]: Invalid user  from 192.168.1.34 port 58180
Jul  2 19:23:48 raspberrypi sshd[3625]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  2 19:23:49 raspberrypi sshd[3625]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 58180 [preauth]
Jul  2 19:24:21 raspberrypi sshd[3633]: Invalid user  from 192.168.1.34 port 58271
Jul  2 19:24:21 raspberrypi sshd[3633]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  2 19:24:23 raspberrypi sshd[3633]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 58271 [preauth]
Jul  2 19:24:30 raspberrypi sshd[3641]: Invalid user  from 192.168.1.34 port 58297
Jul  2 19:24:30 raspberrypi sshd[3641]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  2 19:24:31 raspberrypi sshd[3641]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 58297 [preauth]
Jul  2 19:25:17 raspberrypi sshd[3650]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 58433 [preauth]
Jul  2 19:59:40 raspberrypi sshd[4080]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.41 port 38818 [preauth]
Jul  2 20:00:28 raspberrypi sshd[1529]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul  2 20:00:28 raspberrypi sshd[4096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul  2 20:00:28 raspberrypi sshd[4096]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi sshd[4101]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.1.41 port 38820 ssh2
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi sshd[4101]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: New session c3 of user pi.
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi sshd[4113]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.41 port 38820:11: disconnected by user
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi sshd[4113]: Disconnected from 192.168.1.41 port 38820
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi sshd[4101]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
Jul  2 20:00:39 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: Removed session c3.
Jul  2 20:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[4195]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 20:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[4195]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 21:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[4363]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul  2 21:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[4363]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul  2 21:18:09 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session ended: user pi
Jul  2 21:27:49 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[487,root]: session started: user pi permissions f
Jul  2 21:44:31 raspberrypi sshd[4464]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.1.34 port 56299 ssh2
Jul  2 21:44:31 raspberrypi sshd[4464]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Jul  2 21:44:31 raspberrypi systemd-logind[409]: New session c4 of user pi.
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are adding the key for user "pi" but trying to access the system as user "root".

Log into the pi and, as root:

mkdir -p /root/.ssh;
cat /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I have done it now. Log:

Jul  3 08:07:51 raspberrypi sshd[1410]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 61161 [preauth]

PuTTy answered me "server refused privat key"

Comment: does that work?

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: I've set up custom port 9810, and I get such result:   `Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 9810.   Server listening on :: port 9810.
Invalid user login from 192.168.1.34 port 54994  input_userauth_request: invalid user login [preauth]  Connection closed by 192.168.1.34 port 54994 [preauth]` But, if I enable PasswordAuth I successfully enter there.
I do not understand what to fix it

Comment: Your users appear all over the place - pi, dgh, root - what is the account you are trying to log in to?  What is the account you are logging in from?

Comment: The point is that I turned off PasswordAuth, and at that moment authentication should be without any login. The private key should be used. I clapped at the keyboard simple.

Comment: @serginator your comment is unclear. For key based authentication to work the public key needs to be associated with the appropriate user - so it needs to exist in the appropriate users ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Didabling PasswordAuth does not disable authentication, it makes it more secure by requiring (rather then allowing) an alternative method of authentication - typically key based.

Comment: yes, I so have done. In file `root/.ssh/authorized_keys` recorded the public rsa-key. And made. Unsuccessful